# Memory leaks after closing winform with custom table

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

I have C# WinForm dialog which contains custom table control with rows and cells which are all custom controls, too. After closing (not hiding) this dialog I have memory leak (and this is confirmed by .NET memory profiler).

From information I get from profiler I think it deals with disposing of these controls but I am not sure how to fix it.

In table control I have the list of rows:

```
private readonly List<CustomRow> _rows = new List<CustomRow>();
```

In each row I have list of cells:

```
List<CustomCell> _cells = new List<CustomCell>();
```

By now the disposing in controls was done by auto-generated code in designer.cs:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
         components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

But now I think whether I need to move disposing code to .cs file and add something like that, for example for table:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
     if (disposing)
     {
          if (components != null)
          {
              components.Dispose();
          }
          // dispose each row here                
     }
     base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Or this is done automatically and reason of memory leak is different? (What can it be?)

Comment: Just to make sure, you use `Show` and not `ShowDialog` when showing your - hm, dialog? And the `Dispose` method is called?

Comment: @IvanStoev I use Show(), not ShowDialog(). One more important thing is that these dialogs are not displayed directly but added as controls to tabbed form (one per tab) and then Show() is called for main form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern of `Dispose` is different than what you think it does. `Dispose` doesn't prevent memory leaks.

The dispose pattern is used for preventing unmanaged memory leaks using unmanage code. Meaning, if you use unmanaged code/libaries, you should call a deinitialize (of the unmanaged code) on the Dispose method.

---

The problem you're facing is that you have a dataset that lives longer than your form. Meaning, when a control registeres events on a datarow/table *(like RowChanged events)*, the form is kept *alive* by the data control which is referenced *(because of an eventhandler)* by the dataset. Remember, event handlers are strong references and can cause memoryleaks like yours.

I don't know what components you're using, but you probably could create an easy fix for this.

For example:
When the form is closing/closed just reset the `GridView1.DataSource = Null`. This will force the component to deregister changing/changed events of the `DataTable`

*so the way you 'bind' the data to the components, just 'unbind' it the same way and profile again*

Comment: Thanks, I think you may be correct. The components are written by ourselves. Databinding is not used, for adding data, just addRow() method is used. I can clear everything by method clearAll(). Do you think I should try to call it when form is disposed?

Comment: You should check if you are registering events on the `DataTable/DataSet`. If so, unregister them on the Dispose/Closing